# how to write Junit test case for DatabaseConnecity Status?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to write **Junit test case** for Database Connectivity Status in spring boot  ?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Database connection is a part of integration Test scenario, not a Junit case(which independently check your code and most important a single unit). However if you need to test the JDBC connection with a JUnit , this code might help.

```
 @Inject
    JDBCConfig JdbcConfig;

    //DB Connection checking
    @Test
    public void testConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = JdbcConfig.getConnection();
        Assert.assertNotNull(con);
        con.close();
    }
```